# missing required parameter: client_id

Tags: oauth-2.0, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-account

I tried to request a oauth token from hms server, but it always return `missing required parameter: client_id` to me.

```
url: https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX

header: Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

response: 
{
    "sub_error": 20001,
    "error_description": "missing required parameter: client_id",
    "error": 1102
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because the params should be set in `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
url: https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/token

header: Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

x-www-form-urlencoded:
grant_type    client_credentials
client_id     XX
client_secret XX
```

Answer (score 2):

```
"sub_error": 20001,
"error_description": "missing required parameter: client_id",
"error": 1102
```

[image]

Based on the error information, and according to this [Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/open-platform-error-0000001053869182#section6581130161218), It can be determined that the `client_id` field is empty or incorrect.

You could refer to [this Docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/open-platform-oauth-0000001053629189#section12493191334711) to set.

[image]

Comment: The client_id is the same as the app_id in `agconnect-services.json`?

Comment: The client_id is the same as the app_id in agconnect-services.json?---yes