# Huawei OAuth 2.0 with Spring Security causes "missing required parameter: client_id"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, huawei-developers, huawei-account

I have the following Spring Security configuration:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          huawei:
            client_id: blablabla
            client-secret: blablabla
            redirect-uri: 'http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/huawei'
            scope: openid
        huawei:
          authorization-uri: https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/authorize
          token-uri: https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/token
          user-info-uri: https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
          user-name-attribute: login
```

Same configurations works well with a big number of different OAuth Providers, and I see that Spring sends proper request to Huawei OAuth Provider:

```
20:27:23.497 [parallel-5] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultServerRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'https://oauth-login.cloud.huawei.com/oauth2/v3/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<MY ID HERE>&scope=openid&state=<...>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/huawei&nonce=<...>'
```

But Spring receives an erroneous response:

```
[{sub_error=20001, error_description=missing required parameter: client_id, error=1102}]
```

[Short answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111479/missing-required-parameter-client-id) for a custom OAuth client and is related to the thing that clientId is expected in `x-www-form-urlencoded`, but the question still remains: how to change my **Spring Security configuration** to make it work?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `client-id` and not `client_id` in your yaml file?

Comment: Yes this was also my first guess, but did not work as well unfortunately

Comment: [This documentation page](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/server-error-codes-0000001062371380) makes me think that the `1102` `20001` error you get is not related to the authorization-code request you trace (which contains a `client_id` parameter). Maybe the token request after the authorization-code is returned? You should trace this request to check (it is not going through your browser, don't look for it there, it is an exchange between Spring client and authorization server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Spring Security configuration* has property `user-info-authentication-method` on `provider` level. It configures a way of passing `clientId` and `clientSecret` to OAuth2 Server.
`user-info-authentication-method` has the following values:

- header (it's default value)
- form
- query

So you need to use `form` for Huawei OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to set `ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST` instead of the default `CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC`.

```java
ClientRegistration clientRegistration = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(OAUTH_REGISTRATION_ID)
//...
.clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_POST)
.build();
```